# Search for Data under Tableau Server is blank

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau Client 2020.2 and in Tableau Server I have Site Admin Creator role.
From Tableau client I am able to successfully connect to Tableau Server. But under "Search for Data" when I am clicking the Tableau Server option the screen is blank and not populating any data source that is present in the Tableau Server.

Comment: Make sure you're connected to the same site as where your data sources are published to.

Comment: @Bernardo, Yes,the tableau server link where data sources are publish and to which i am trying to connect is same.